# Getting text between two empty lines in haskell

Tags: haskell, io

Hey i am back with another haskell question. I asked a question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345442/empty-space-work-around-in-haskell/34345720#34345720) and now i can get the empty lines perfectly, now i want to try to get the text between two specific empty lines in haskell.(For example i will get the text between the beginning and first empty line.) I can't think of any ways to do that in haskell because i can't understand the syntax and use it efficiently so i really need your help. My practice about doing some io stuff is like following;`

```
main=do{
readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" >>= print . length . filter (== '?');
readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" >>= print . length . words;
readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" >>= print . length . filter (== '.');
readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" >>= print . length . filter null . lines;
}`
```

With this, i can count the number of sentences, number of question marks, number of empty lines and so on. Now i want to get the text between two empty lines. I would be very pleased if you help me with this last exercise of mine that i couldn't solve. Thanks from now!

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're using brackets and semicolons? Haskell's syntax is designed so that you don't need them and the idiomatic style is to not use them.

Comment: Have you looked at the [split](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) library?

Comment: Oh i don't know when i delete the semicolons and the brackets, the code is not working

Comment: You need to use [indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).

Comment: Maybe you should work through some introductory tutorials for Haskell? Haskell.org has a list of resources: https://www.haskell.org/documentation

Comment: I know i am studying but i couldn't find the helper in any tutorial for this problem :/

Comment: Programming is about finding solutions to problems using the tools that you have available. You shouldn't expect to find a tutorial for every problem. An introductory tutorial would teach you about the basic problem-solving tools and also about fundamental concepts—like the syntax of the language—which are requirements for progressing further in your studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pattern-matching, it literally says what it does:

```
betweenEmptyLines :: [String] -> [String]
betweenEmptyLines [] = []
betweenEmptyLines ("":line:"":rest) = line:(betweenEmptyLines $ "":rest)
betweenEmptyLines (line:rest) = betweenEmptyLines rest
```

How it works:

```
> betweenEmptyLines ["foo", "", "the bar", "", "and", "also", "", "the baz", "", "but", "not", "rest"]
["the bar","the baz"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the functions `lines`, `groupBy` and `filter`

- `lines` is used to split a `String` in a list of Strings (one line for each element)
- `groupBy` groups then all lines that are non-empty - this should be the most difficult part you have to write a predicate that is true for two succeeding elements if they are non-empty: `groupBy (\x y -> ???)`
- then `filter` out the elements of shape `[""]`

here some example usage in ghci

```
λ > import Data.List
λ > let groupify = ???
λ > l <- readFile "~/tmux.conf"
λ > map length $ groupify l
[4,7,3,1,4,2,2,5,4,3,3,2,7,4,4,4,3,3,3,2]
```

you can check with the contents of my tmux config file at my [github-repo](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/dotfiles/blob/master/_tmux.conf)

### UPDATE

the solution for this problem would be

> `groupify = filter (/= [""]) . groupBy (\x y -> x /= "" && y /= "") . lines`

Comment: But what if the string is a paragraph? How will haskell get the correct answer in that case? Let's say between two empty lines there is a long paragraph in the file we are reading. What we should do in that case?

Comment: The result according to this algorithm will be a list of lists of Strings, where each list in this list is a list of lines, i.e., a paragraph.

Comment: as user2407038 explained - this algorithm returns a list of strings where each list element is just a paragraph, with empty lines stripped out, also if you look closely at my tmux config there are 2 empty lines in it!